# Does the solution exist in this matrix system?

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra

I got these equations after the post process, so I just listed the numerical equations, and there are 50 equations total with 50 unknown variables, however, the
`Solve` and `NSolve` cannot get the solution.

So is this system (maybe linear) have the solution, and how to decompose the system to `Ax=b` and how to extract matrix `A` and matrix `b` to judge its rank or use the `LinearSolve` to solve this system?

By the way, as I cannot use all symbolic calculations to get the equation, for example, initially when assigning the values, I use `13/10` rather than `1.3` to do the calculation, so but the `MatrixExp` is and `Inverse` is very slow and cannot carry on when the matrix size is bigger, so I finally I used the input values in the style of `1.3`, and after several calculations to get the 50 equations. In this process, I suspect that Mathematica has changed the accuracy of the equation, for example, I do not know what the following accuracy will affect the final result, and I just copy the equations from Mathematica notebook.

```
**{(4.763351335421033`*^-18 - 5.757948863725194`*^-17 I) + 0.0398837643080161` aIVcoefficient[1] - 0.07942645028395248` aIVcoefficient[2] + 1.` aIVcoefficient[3]**
```

The above will lost the accuracy, but maybe no better way?

The following is the code:

```
   equa = {{(0.` + 0.` I) + 0.6815984732601709` aIcoefficient[1] - 
         0.6815984732601709` aIIcoefficient[1] + 
         1.467139436532002` bIcoefficient[1] - 
         1.467139436532002` bIIcoefficient[1]}, {(0.8073527509320696` + 
           0.12787211360085063` I) + 
         0.8255897729866637` aIcoefficient[2] - 
         0.8255897729866637` aIIcoefficient[2] + 
         1.2112553143462372` bIcoefficient[2] - 
         1.2112553143462372` bIIcoefficient[2]}, {(0.` + 0.` I) + 
         1.` aIcoefficient[3] - 1.` aIIcoefficient[3] + 
         1.` bIcoefficient[3] - 
         1.` bIIcoefficient[3]}, {(0.8073527509320696` - 
           0.12787211360085063` I) + 
         0.8255897729866637` aIcoefficient[4] - 
         0.8255897729866637` aIIcoefficient[4] + 
         1.2112553143462372` bIcoefficient[4] - 
         1.2112553143462372` bIIcoefficient[4]}, {(0.` + 0.` I) + 
         0.6815984732601709` aIcoefficient[5] - 
         0.6815984732601709` aIIcoefficient[5] + 
         1.467139436532002` bIcoefficient[5] - 
         1.467139436532002` bIIcoefficient[5]}, {0.` + 
         24459.924740303326` aIcoefficient[1] - 
         2.4459924740303326`*^7 aIIcoefficient[1] - 
         52649.94217116712` bIcoefficient[1] + 
         5.264994217116712`*^7 bIIcoefficient[1]}, {0.` + 
         14813.606915100705` aIcoefficient[2] - 
         1.4813606915100705`*^7 aIIcoefficient[2] - 
         21733.62690242742` bIcoefficient[2] + 
         2.1733626902427416`*^7 bIIcoefficient[2]}, {0.`}, {0.` + 
         14813.606915100705` aIcoefficient[4] - 
         1.4813606915100705`*^7 aIIcoefficient[4] - 
         21733.62690242742` bIcoefficient[4] + 
         2.1733626902427416`*^7 bIIcoefficient[4]}, {0.` + 
         24459.924740303326` aIcoefficient[5] - 
         2.4459924740303326`*^7 aIIcoefficient[5] - 
         52649.94217116712` bIcoefficient[5] + 
         5.264994217116712`*^7 bIIcoefficient[5]}, {(0.` + 0.` I) + 
         0.544006716016415` aIIcoefficient[1] - 
         0.544006716016415` aIIIcoefficient[1] + 
         1.8382126002463282` bIIcoefficient[1] - 
         1.8382126002463282` bIIIcoefficient[
           1]}, {(-0.8073527509320696` - 0.12787211360085063` I) + 
         0.7375681094084905` aIIcoefficient[2] - 
         0.7375681094084905` aIIIcoefficient[2] + 
         1.3558069922545495` bIIcoefficient[2] - 
         1.3558069922545495` bIIIcoefficient[2]}, {(0.` + 0.` I) + 
         1.` aIIcoefficient[3] - 1.` aIIIcoefficient[3] + 
         1.` bIIcoefficient[3] - 
         1.` bIIIcoefficient[3]}, {(-0.8073527509320696` + 
           0.12787211360085063` I) + 
         0.7375681094084905` aIIcoefficient[4] - 
         0.7375681094084905` aIIIcoefficient[4] + 
         1.3558069922545495` bIIcoefficient[4] - 
         1.3558069922545495` bIIIcoefficient[4]}, {(0.` + 0.` I) + 
         0.544006716016415` aIIcoefficient[5] - 
         0.544006716016415` aIIIcoefficient[5] + 
         1.8382126002463282` bIIcoefficient[5] - 
         1.8382126002463282` bIIIcoefficient[5]}, {0.` + 
         1.952229040117281`*^7 aIIcoefficient[1] - 
         1.952229040117281`*^7 aIIIcoefficient[1] - 
         6.59663183276233`*^7 bIIcoefficient[1] + 
         6.59663183276233`*^7 bIIIcoefficient[1]}, {0.` + 
         1.3234228915366983`*^7 aIIcoefficient[2] - 
         1.3234228915366983`*^7 aIIIcoefficient[2] - 
         2.4327326346771885`*^7 bIIcoefficient[2] + 
         2.4327326346771885`*^7 bIIIcoefficient[2]}, {0.`}, {0.` + 
         1.3234228915366983`*^7 aIIcoefficient[4] - 
         1.3234228915366983`*^7 aIIIcoefficient[4] - 
         2.4327326346771885`*^7 bIIcoefficient[4] + 
         2.4327326346771885`*^7 bIIIcoefficient[4]}, {0.` + 
         1.952229040117281`*^7 aIIcoefficient[5] - 
         1.952229040117281`*^7 aIIIcoefficient[5] - 
         6.59663183276233`*^7 bIIcoefficient[5] + 
         6.59663183276233`*^7 bIIIcoefficient[
           5]}, {0.527102228842787` aIIIcoefficient[1] - 
         0.902104931583961` aIVcoefficient[1] - 
         0.03810467543486388` aIVcoefficient[2] + 
         1.9796065676594032`*^-18 aIVcoefficient[3] + 
         0.03225197484587826` aIVcoefficient[4] - 
         0.013436568705534946` aIVcoefficient[5] + 
         1.89716518974967` bIIIcoefficient[1] - 
         1.113571355149769` bIVcoefficient[1] + 
         0.052510035946752916` bIVcoefficient[2] - 
         1.1669034626942133`*^-18 bIVcoefficient[3] - 
         0.044892482120949935` bIVcoefficient[4] + 
         0.020335107226451044` bIVcoefficient[
           5]}, {0.7260180637165904` aIIIcoefficient[2] - 
         0.09863741283654497` aIVcoefficient[1] - 
         0.8295030028081504` aIVcoefficient[2] + 
         2.9447225657865545`*^-17 aIVcoefficient[3] - 
         0.010449635327188143` aIVcoefficient[4] - 
         0.019924873066124338` aIVcoefficient[5] + 
         1.3773761976125731` bIIIcoefficient[2] + 
         0.13164233320918256` bIVcoefficient[1] - 
         1.2109503935218189` bIVcoefficient[2] - 
         3.507565804313883`*^-17 bIVcoefficient[3] + 
         0.0193318317698859` bIVcoefficient[4] + 
         0.022671830114584512` bIVcoefficient[5]}, {1.` aIIIcoefficient[
           3] - 0.03494831300401707` aIVcoefficient[1] + 
         0.06856891768501899` aIVcoefficient[2] - 
         1.0000000000000002` aIVcoefficient[3] + 
         0.0685689176850185` aIVcoefficient[4] - 
         0.03494831300401713` aIVcoefficient[5] + 
         1.` bIIIcoefficient[3] + 
         0.04878791774234126` bIVcoefficient[1] - 
         0.08197421572813807` bIVcoefficient[2] - 
         1.0000000000000002` bIVcoefficient[3] - 
         0.08197421572813762` bIVcoefficient[4] + 
         0.04878791774234126` bIVcoefficient[
           5]}, {0.7260180637165904` aIIIcoefficient[4] - 
         0.019924873066123804` aIVcoefficient[1] - 
         0.010449635327188313` aIVcoefficient[2] + 
         1.2828468405456788`*^-17 aIVcoefficient[3] - 
         0.8295030028081509` aIVcoefficient[4] - 
         0.09863741283654433` aIVcoefficient[5] + 
         1.3773761976125731` bIIIcoefficient[4] + 
         0.022671830114583937` bIVcoefficient[1] + 
         0.01933183176988634` bIVcoefficient[2] - 
         1.4485740430212436`*^-17 bIVcoefficient[3] - 
         1.2109503935218184` bIVcoefficient[4] + 
         0.13164233320918195` bIVcoefficient[
           5]}, {0.527102228842787` aIIIcoefficient[5] - 
         0.013436568705534948` aIVcoefficient[1] + 
         0.03225197484587825` aIVcoefficient[2] + 
         3.3024962924608757`*^-18 aIVcoefficient[3] - 
         0.03810467543486375` aIVcoefficient[4] - 
         0.9021049315839611` aIVcoefficient[5] + 
         1.89716518974967` bIIIcoefficient[5] + 
         0.02033510722645093` bIVcoefficient[1] - 
         0.04489248212094991` bIVcoefficient[2] - 
         4.285645474198178`*^-18 bIVcoefficient[3] + 
         0.05251003594675275` bIVcoefficient[4] - 
         1.1135713551497688` bIVcoefficient[5]}, {0.` + 
         1.8915653942521974`*^7 aIIIcoefficient[1] - 
         4.808151902260667`*^6 aIVcoefficient[1] + 
         3.9455190357605047`*^6 aIVcoefficient[2] + 
         5.014167210139676`*^-10 aIVcoefficient[3] - 
         651517.4822687587` aIVcoefficient[4] - 
         421069.88318322925` aIVcoefficient[5] - 
         6.808189804070656`*^7 bIIIcoefficient[1] + 
         7.144448826363817`*^6 bIVcoefficient[1] - 
         6.394654832194837`*^6 bIVcoefficient[2] - 
         7.754025181791637`*^-10 bIVcoefficient[3] + 
         1.6224348101310125`*^6 bIVcoefficient[4] + 
         272900.58979143936` bIVcoefficient[5]}, {0.` + 
         1.30269857513531`*^7 aIIIcoefficient[2] + 
         3.9455190357604977`*^6 aIVcoefficient[1] - 
         5.1726437672463795`*^6 aIVcoefficient[2] - 
         6.085056089984946`*^-10 aIVcoefficient[3] + 
         2.814432666158135`*^6 aIVcoefficient[4] - 
         651517.4822687613` aIVcoefficient[5] - 
         2.4714343894832052`*^7 bIIIcoefficient[2] - 
         6.39465483219483`*^6 bIVcoefficient[1] + 
         8.320611019494848`*^6 bIVcoefficient[2] + 
         9.220637370463883`*^-10 bIVcoefficient[3] - 
         4.911953674228196`*^6 bIVcoefficient[4] + 
         1.6224348101310069`*^6 bIVcoefficient[5]}, {0.` + 
         7.421294256748206`*^-9 aIVcoefficient[1] - 
         4.947529504498804`*^-9 aIVcoefficient[2] + 
         1.2348119723278187`*^-10 aIVcoefficient[3] + 
         3.003857199159988`*^-9 aIVcoefficient[4] + 
         1.117611575569819`*^-8 aIVcoefficient[5] - 
         9.54166404439055`*^-9 bIVcoefficient[1] + 
         7.774689221355263`*^-9 bIVcoefficient[2] - 
         1.2348119723278164`*^-10 bIVcoefficient[3] - 
         4.240739575284689`*^-9 bIVcoefficient[4] - 
         1.2898916208157596`*^-8 bIVcoefficient[5]}, {0.` + 
         1.30269857513531`*^7 aIIIcoefficient[4] - 
         651517.4822687615` aIVcoefficient[1] + 
         2.814432666158148`*^6 aIVcoefficient[2] - 
         2.427150337247048`*^-10 aIVcoefficient[3] - 
         5.172643767246372`*^6 aIVcoefficient[4] + 
         3.9455190357604926`*^6 aIVcoefficient[5] - 
         2.4714343894832052`*^7 bIIIcoefficient[4] + 
         1.622434810131026`*^6 bIVcoefficient[1] - 
         4.911953674228223`*^6 bIVcoefficient[2] + 
         1.4696843914103367`*^-10 bIVcoefficient[3] + 
         8.320611019494826`*^6 bIVcoefficient[4] - 
         6.394654832194806`*^6 bIVcoefficient[5]}, {0.` + 
         1.8915653942521974`*^7 aIIIcoefficient[5] - 
         421069.8831832276` aIVcoefficient[1] - 
         651517.4822687629` aIVcoefficient[2] + 
         4.5726499919469627`*^-10 aIVcoefficient[3] + 
         3.945519035760497`*^6 aIVcoefficient[4] - 
         4.808151902260664`*^6 aIVcoefficient[5] - 
         6.808189804070656`*^7 bIIIcoefficient[5] + 
         272900.58979142876` bIVcoefficient[1] + 
         1.6224348101310222`*^6 bIVcoefficient[2] - 
         4.805916489969915`*^-10 bIVcoefficient[3] - 
         6.3946548321948135`*^6 bIVcoefficient[4] + 
         7.144448826363801`*^6 bIVcoefficient[
           5]}, {(-0.0017322378178796418` - 0.026907023612397867` I) + 
         0.8862731430073842` aIVcoefficient[1] + 
         0.0435910038025796` aIVcoefficient[2] - 
         2.392167074317305`*^-18 aIVcoefficient[3] - 
         0.036864563217668886` aIVcoefficient[4] + 
         0.015234287295908198` aIVcoefficient[5] - 
         0.7818791967905447` aVcoefficient[1] + 
         0.0567718703104632` aVcoefficient[2] + 
         1.781270791572057`*^-17 aVcoefficient[3] - 
         0.024450167285175826` aVcoefficient[4] - 
         0.013896267538051722` aVcoefficient[5] + 
         1.1354410995353608` bIVcoefficient[1] - 
         0.06355943603318351` bIVcoefficient[2] + 
         1.2646135041853175`*^-18 bIVcoefficient[3] + 
         0.054388877086034515` bIVcoefficient[4] - 
         0.024801777692165558` bIVcoefficient[5] - 
         1.3093308558303136` bVcoefficient[1] - 
         0.09629591944572383` bVcoefficient[2] + 
         4.511148910838657`*^-18 bVcoefficient[3] + 
         0.04425288414665807` bVcoefficient[4] + 
         0.04332308517158867` bVcoefficient[
           5]}, {(-0.03828217746866802` - 0.0843441425243542` I) + 
         0.11313655266643213` aIVcoefficient[1] + 
         0.8030327158896496` aIVcoefficient[2] - 
         3.412739005320015`*^-17 aIVcoefficient[3] + 
         0.011601315983215059` aIVcoefficient[4] + 
         0.023125700905252122` aIVcoefficient[5] + 
         0.2097356768238431` aVcoefficient[1] - 
         0.7839756217397915` aVcoefficient[2] + 
         3.0684623915111367`*^-17 aVcoefficient[3] - 
         0.002287649719937317` aVcoefficient[4] - 
         0.06643270656660281` aVcoefficient[5] - 
         0.158865449095193` bIVcoefficient[1] + 
         1.2530134394042658` bIVcoefficient[2] + 
         4.1922545531818625`*^-17 bIVcoefficient[3] - 
         0.023934415137685572` bIVcoefficient[4] - 
         0.026909034879838156` bIVcoefficient[5] - 
         0.3543147903282006` bVcoefficient[1] - 
         1.3051311328355724` bVcoefficient[2] - 
         1.9221849581814614`*^-17 bVcoefficient[3] + 
         0.023807232675295054` bVcoefficient[4] + 
         0.12357442575880696` bVcoefficient[
           5]}, {(4.763351335421033`*^-18 - 5.757948863725194`*^-17 I) + 
         0.0398837643080161` aIVcoefficient[1] - 
         0.07942645028395248` aIVcoefficient[2] + 1.` aIVcoefficient[3] - 
         0.07942645028395198` aIVcoefficient[4] + 
         0.039883764308016156` aIVcoefficient[5] - 
         0.020402081708550294` aVcoefficient[1] + 
         0.1746125536318779` aVcoefficient[2] - 
         1.0000000000000002` aVcoefficient[3] + 
         0.1746125536318778` aVcoefficient[4] - 
         0.020402081708552733` aVcoefficient[5] - 
         0.05905188475907842` bIVcoefficient[1] + 
         0.0979871404275791` bIVcoefficient[2] + 1.` bIVcoefficient[3] + 
         0.09798714042757863` bIVcoefficient[4] - 
         0.0590518847590783` bIVcoefficient[5] - 
         0.014460970302774045` bVcoefficient[1] - 
         0.22267345197801064` bVcoefficient[2] - 
         1.0000000000000002` bVcoefficient[3] - 
         0.22267345197800925` bVcoefficient[4] - 
         0.014460970302769603` bVcoefficient[
           5]}, {(-0.03828217746866845` + 0.08434414252435436` I) + 
         0.02312570090525179` aIVcoefficient[1] + 
         0.011601315983215277` aIVcoefficient[2] - 
         1.4926070905077245`*^-17 aIVcoefficient[3] + 
         0.8030327158896501` aIVcoefficient[4] + 
         0.11313655266643143` aIVcoefficient[5] - 
         0.06643270656660208` aVcoefficient[1] - 
         0.0022876497199371395` aVcoefficient[2] - 
         9.152794752285988`*^-17 aVcoefficient[3] - 
         0.7839756217397928` aVcoefficient[4] + 
         0.20973567682384162` aVcoefficient[5] - 
         0.026909034879837847` bIVcoefficient[1] - 
         0.023934415137686238` bIVcoefficient[2] + 
         1.7217694314674187`*^-17 bIVcoefficient[3] + 
         1.253013439404265` bIVcoefficient[4] - 
         0.15886544909519204` bIVcoefficient[5] + 
         0.1235744257588055` bVcoefficient[1] + 
         0.02380723267529489` bVcoefficient[2] - 
         2.220522317085354`*^-17 bVcoefficient[3] - 
         1.3051311328355697` bVcoefficient[4] - 
         0.35431479032819757` bVcoefficient[
           5]}, {(-0.0017322378178794388` + 0.02690702361239803` I) + 
         0.0152342872959082` aIVcoefficient[1] - 
         0.03686456321766886` aIVcoefficient[2] - 
         3.79996469960318`*^-18 aIVcoefficient[3] + 
         0.043591003802579485` aIVcoefficient[4] + 
         0.8862731430073844` aIVcoefficient[5] - 
         0.013896267538051532` aVcoefficient[1] - 
         0.02445016728517598` aVcoefficient[2] + 
         1.0055530360521509`*^-16 aVcoefficient[3] + 
         0.05677187031046276` aVcoefficient[4] - 
         0.7818791967905452` aVcoefficient[5] - 
         0.024801777692165416` bIVcoefficient[1] + 
         0.05438887708603458` bIVcoefficient[2] + 
         5.1627638746858775`*^-18 bIVcoefficient[3] - 
         0.06355943603318337` bIVcoefficient[4] + 
         1.1354410995353605` bIVcoefficient[5] + 
         0.04332308517158823` bVcoefficient[1] + 
         0.04425288414665826` bVcoefficient[2] - 
         1.7166789232538527`*^-17 bVcoefficient[3] - 
         0.09629591944572274` bVcoefficient[4] - 
         1.309330855830312` bVcoefficient[
           5]}, {4.646751185471299`*^6 aIVcoefficient[1] - 
         3.780945048645965`*^6 aIVcoefficient[2] - 
         4.827249369520237`*^-10 aIVcoefficient[3] + 
         592771.5660010556` aIVcoefficient[4] + 
         424926.4542889232` aIVcoefficient[5] - 
         340250.5153765599` aVcoefficient[1] + 
         160852.02024063247` aVcoefficient[2] - 
         5.495451723404348`*^-11 aVcoefficient[3] - 
         129052.44118121795` aVcoefficient[4] + 
         204066.9736389931` aVcoefficient[5] - 
         7.403000687430209`*^6 bIVcoefficient[1] + 
         6.671936269206717`*^6 bIVcoefficient[2] + 
         8.060078235187699`*^-10 bIVcoefficient[3] - 
         1.7415169013702518`*^6 bIVcoefficient[4] - 
         247425.38813345888` bIVcoefficient[5] + 
         94838.28041971105` bVcoefficient[1] - 
         44677.45386916875` bVcoefficient[2] + 
         3.242646313370151`*^-11 bVcoefficient[3] + 
         23730.524379016948` bVcoefficient[4] - 
         35094.97727966463` bVcoefficient[
           5]}, {-3.7809450486459574`*^6 aIVcoefficient[1] + 
         4.962408758996038`*^6 aIVcoefficient[2] + 
         5.871766352214633`*^-10 aIVcoefficient[3] - 
         2.6794448759045843`*^6 aIVcoefficient[4] + 
         592771.5660010569` aIVcoefficient[5] + 
         160852.02024063512` aVcoefficient[1] - 
         101538.70755824399` aVcoefficient[2] + 
         6.36591010227174`*^-11 aVcoefficient[3] + 
         72933.57637043372` aVcoefficient[4] - 
         129052.44118121683` aVcoefficient[5] + 
         6.671936269206713`*^6 bIVcoefficient[1] - 
         8.679007297767732`*^6 bIVcoefficient[2] - 
         9.57219217837519`*^-10 bIVcoefficient[3] + 
         5.157985077441051`*^6 bIVcoefficient[4] - 
         1.7415169013702462`*^6 bIVcoefficient[5] - 
         71571.09659449034` bVcoefficient[1] + 
         31821.95762665411` bVcoefficient[2] - 
         4.4076038659483016`*^-11 bVcoefficient[3] - 
         6716.420210295398` bVcoefficient[4] + 
         1519.973256862665` bVcoefficient[
           5]}, {-7.067899292141148`*^-9 aIVcoefficient[1] + 
         4.947529504498803`*^-9 aIVcoefficient[2] - 
         1.2348119723278202`*^-10 aIVcoefficient[3] - 
         3.4014265343429277`*^-9 aIVcoefficient[4] - 
         1.1220290126274072`*^-8 aIVcoefficient[5] - 
         4.947529504498803`*^-9 aVcoefficient[1] + 
         2.1203697876423445`*^-9 aVcoefficient[2] - 
         6.147334204074303`*^-11 aVcoefficient[3] - 
         4.417437057588218`*^-9 aVcoefficient[4] + 
         2.1203697876423445`*^-9 aVcoefficient[5] + 
         9.895059008997607`*^-9 bIVcoefficient[1] - 
         6.361109362927034`*^-9 bIVcoefficient[2] + 
         1.2348119723278164`*^-10 bIVcoefficient[3] + 
         4.240739575284689`*^-9 bIVcoefficient[4] + 
         1.3163962431612888`*^-8 bIVcoefficient[5] + 
         36881.867243375134` bVcoefficient[1] - 
         13276.604734541737` bVcoefficient[2] + 
         5.1405592897502476`*^-11 bVcoefficient[3] - 
         13276.604734534103` bVcoefficient[4] + 
         36881.86724337187` bVcoefficient[
           5]}, {592771.5660010583` aIVcoefficient[1] - 
         2.679444875904597`*^6 aIVcoefficient[2] + 
         2.484361054137977`*^-10 aIVcoefficient[3] + 
         4.962408758996029`*^6 aIVcoefficient[4] - 
         3.780945048645952`*^6 aIVcoefficient[5] - 
         129052.4411812103` aVcoefficient[1] + 
         72933.57637042785` aVcoefficient[2] + 
         5.179665112159971`*^-11 aVcoefficient[3] - 
         101538.70755823726` aVcoefficient[4] + 
         160852.02024062825` aVcoefficient[5] - 
         1.7415169013702658`*^6 bIVcoefficient[1] + 
         5.15798507744108`*^6 bIVcoefficient[2] - 
         1.351054798740686`*^-10 bIVcoefficient[3] - 
         8.679007297767706`*^6 bIVcoefficient[4] + 
         6.671936269206684`*^6 bIVcoefficient[5] + 
         1519.9732568598183` bVcoefficient[1] - 
         6716.420210288418` bVcoefficient[2] - 
         5.2790866798381914`*^-11 bVcoefficient[3] + 
         31821.957626646723` bVcoefficient[4] - 
         71571.09659448701` bVcoefficient[
           5]}, {424926.4542889205` aIVcoefficient[1] + 
         592771.5660010596` aIVcoefficient[2] - 
         4.5474776083295977`*^-10 aIVcoefficient[3] - 
         3.780945048645958`*^6 aIVcoefficient[4] + 
         4.646751185471296`*^6 aIVcoefficient[5] + 
         204066.9736389881` aVcoefficient[1] - 
         129052.44118121365` aVcoefficient[2] - 
         3.2082460409503426`*^-11 aVcoefficient[3] + 
         160852.02024062644` aVcoefficient[4] - 
         340250.5153765538` aVcoefficient[5] - 
         247425.38813344805` bIVcoefficient[1] - 
         1.741516901370262`*^6 bIVcoefficient[2] + 
         4.81898320148912`*^-10 bIVcoefficient[3] + 
         6.671936269206694`*^6 bIVcoefficient[4] - 
         7.40300068743019`*^6 bIVcoefficient[5] - 
         35094.97727966243` bVcoefficient[1] + 
         23730.524379011324` bVcoefficient[2] + 
         4.790753019328496`*^-11 bVcoefficient[3] - 
         44677.45386916243` bVcoefficient[4] + 
         94838.28041970811` bVcoefficient[5]}, {1.` aIcoefficient[1] + 
         1.` bIcoefficient[1]}, {1.` aIcoefficient[2] + 
         1.` bIcoefficient[2]}, {1.` aIcoefficient[3] + 
         1.` bIcoefficient[3]}, {1.` aIcoefficient[4] + 
         1.` bIcoefficient[4]}, {1.` aIcoefficient[5] + 
         1.` bIcoefficient[5]}, {(-1.2133945259254957` + 
           0.07811669979164113` I) + (0.` + 
            27.72502160734832` I) aVcoefficient[
           1] - (0.` + 4.068360294401766` I) aVcoefficient[
           2] - (0.` + 3.060402098430089`*^-16 I) aVcoefficient[
           3] + (0.` + 1.7157479167334777` I) aVcoefficient[
           4] + (0.` + 0.558656889210907` I) aVcoefficient[
           5] + (0.` + 81.08978940071115` I) bVcoefficient[
           1] + (0.` + 12.202478345059541` I) bVcoefficient[
           2] - (0.` + 4.881152774367718`*^-16 I) bVcoefficient[
           3] - (0.` + 5.872668419489061` I) bVcoefficient[
           4] - (0.` + 6.854120705090718` I) bVcoefficient[
           5]}, {(-1.901784498858043` + 
           0.8631832574671483` I) - (0.` + 
            7.524393801411527` I) aVcoefficient[
           1] + (0.` + 13.933415009563763` I) aVcoefficient[
           2] - (0.` + 1.0146543872206155`*^-15 I) aVcoefficient[
           3] - (0.` + 0.13775960352412106` I) aVcoefficient[
           4] + (0.` + 2.3090692666855874` I) aVcoefficient[
           5] + (0.` + 22.380656530476674` I) bVcoefficient[
           1] + (0.` + 40.24812651369694` I) bVcoefficient[
           2] + (0.` + 9.408143479383613`*^-16 I) bVcoefficient[
           3] - (0.` + 2.1988688929825155` I) bVcoefficient[
           4] - (0.` + 8.348590169549814` I) bVcoefficient[5]}, {0.` + 
         0.` I}, {(-1.9017844988580466` - 
           0.863183257467158` I) - (0.` + 
            2.3090692666855674` I) aVcoefficient[
           1] + (0.` + 0.1377596035241246` I) aVcoefficient[
           2] - (0.` + 1.7389583178924158`*^-15 I) aVcoefficient[
           3] - (0.` + 13.933415009563806` I) aVcoefficient[
           4] + (0.` + 7.5243938014114855` I) aVcoefficient[
           5] + (0.` + 8.348590169549723` I) bVcoefficient[
           1] + (0.` + 2.198868892982503` I) bVcoefficient[
           2] - (0.` + 1.3713357189750004`*^-15 I) bVcoefficient[
           3] - (0.` + 40.248126513696754` I) bVcoefficient[
           4] - (0.` + 22.380656530476436` I) bVcoefficient[
           5]}, {(-1.213394525925503` - 
           0.07811669979163197` I) - (0.` + 
            0.5586568892108987` I) aVcoefficient[
           1] - (0.` + 1.7157479167334848` I) aVcoefficient[
           2] + (0.` + 4.3806228247859174`*^-15 I) aVcoefficient[
           3] + (0.` + 4.068360294401739` I) aVcoefficient[
           4] - (0.` + 27.725021607348335` I) aVcoefficient[
           5] + (0.` + 6.854120705090679` I) bVcoefficient[
           1] + (0.` + 5.872668419489085` I) bVcoefficient[
           2] - (0.` + 1.955539387118312`*^-15 I) bVcoefficient[
           3] - (0.` + 12.202478345059394` I) bVcoefficient[
           4] - (0.` + 81.08978940071094` I) bVcoefficient[5]}};
    equaRight = Transpose[{Table[0, {eqauRightIndex, 1, (2*NN + 1)*10}]}]
    varibales = {aIcoefficient[1], aIcoefficient[2], aIcoefficient[3], 
       aIcoefficient[4], aIcoefficient[5], aIIcoefficient[1], 
       aIIcoefficient[2], aIIcoefficient[3], aIIcoefficient[4], 
       aIIcoefficient[5], aIIIcoefficient[1], aIIIcoefficient[2], 
       aIIIcoefficient[3], aIIIcoefficient[4], aIIIcoefficient[5], 
       aIVcoefficient[1], aIVcoefficient[2], aIVcoefficient[3], 
       aIVcoefficient[4], aIVcoefficient[5], aVcoefficient[1], 
       aVcoefficient[2], aVcoefficient[3], aVcoefficient[4], 
       aVcoefficient[5], bIcoefficient[1], bIcoefficient[2], 
       bIcoefficient[3], bIcoefficient[4], bIcoefficient[5], 
       bIIcoefficient[1], bIIcoefficient[2], bIIcoefficient[3], 
       bIIcoefficient[4], bIIcoefficient[5], bIIIcoefficient[1], 
       bIIIcoefficient[2], bIIIcoefficient[3], bIIIcoefficient[4], 
       bIIIcoefficient[5], bIVcoefficient[1], bIVcoefficient[2], 
       bIVcoefficient[3], bIVcoefficient[4], bIVcoefficient[5], 
       bVcoefficient[1], bVcoefficient[2], bVcoefficient[3], 
       bVcoefficient[4], bVcoefficient[5]};
    NSolve[equa == equaRight, varibales]
```

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, your system has a 5-dimensional null space:

```
x = varibales;
A = N[D[equa[[All, 1]], {x, 1}]];
b = equa[[All, 1]] - A . x;
nullspace = NullSpace[A];
Length[nullspace]
```

> 5

Comment: So you mean there is something wrong in these equations? Please can you indicate more clear?

Comment: This system dimension is `A: [50x50], and b: [50x1]`.

Comment: "So you mean there is something wrong in these equations? " Yes. "Please can you indicate more clear?" No. How much clearer do you want it?

Comment: If A has a null space of 5  it means the Determinant is zero and it does not have an inverse. Therefore, the equations are underdetermined. The best you may get is 45 variables as functions of the 5 additional variables.

Comment: So you mean that the rank of `A` is smaller than `x`, so there will be more than on solution in this system? @DanielHuber

Comment: What do you mean "the equations are underdetermined."?@DanielHuber

Comment: In (I hope) simple terms, 5 of your equations are effectively linear combinations of the other 45.  These equations either make it impossible to find a solution (think of `x+y==1&&x+y==2`) or give an infinite number of solutions (think of `x+y==1&&2x+2y==2`).

Comment: "underdetermined" means that your equations can not uniquely determine a solution. If the matrix has not full rank, see the remark of mikado.

Comment: **(The most important, although we can get some solution from multi solutions, as we have to do the postprocess, for example by adding or dividing using these solutions, so different solutions will generate different final results, how to judge which final result is right, if there are all selected from several right solutions?**

Comment: In addition, how to judge whether the rank is lower because of the accuracy loss in the Mathematica calculation process?

Comment: I understand your meaning and `MatrixRank[A]=45` and `MatrixRank[A~Join~{b}]=45`, and `MatrixRank[x]=50`, so it means that there is an infinite solution in this system, rather than no solution. Please how to get some solution using Mathematica?@DanielHuber

Comment: You can try `LeastSquares[A,b]`. If `b` lies in the image of `A`, then it picks the solution with the smallest norm. If `b` does not lie in the image of `A`, then it first determines the orthogonal projection `c` of `b` onto the image of `A` and then picks the solution of `A.x == c` with smallest norm.

Comment: But the fact that the system is degenerate although you seem to expect that it isn't tells me that you might have set up the system incorrectly. Which can mean that you made a simple mistake when typing it into _Mathematica_ or that you overlooked something when you derived it.

Comment: I think your answer is not correct to isolate the `A` and `b`, as there is still the `x` element such as the `aIcoefficient[1]` etc. in the `b` matrix, The correct is that the  `aIcoefficient[1]` should in `x` matrix.@HenrikSchumacher

Comment: I don't understand you. The `b` that I get is `{0. + 0. I, 0.807353 + 0.127872 I, 0. + 0. I, 0.807353 - 0.127872 I, 0. + 0. I, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0. + 0. I, -0.807353 - 0.127872 I, 0. + 0. I, -0.807353 + 0.127872 I, 0. + 0. I, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., -0.00173224 - 0.026907 I, -0.0382822 - 0.0843441 I, 4.76335*10^-18 - 5.75795*10^-17 I, -0.0382822 + 0.0843441 I, -0.00173224 + 0.026907 I, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., -1.21339 + 0.0781167 I, -1.90178 + 0.863183 I, 0. + 0. I, -1.90178 - 0.863183 I, -1.21339 - 0.0781167 I}`.

Comment: So there is no occurency of any symbols whatsoever.